# Loop through table td's to detect child div class

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to loop through all td cells on my table.

The td's contain div's, I need to search each of these div classes to detect a class 'ws_is_all_day_event', if the class is detected I need to add another class 'ws_has_all_day_event' to the parent td.

Currently I can only get this to apply the extra class to all td's, not the specific td column.

[My Code Pen Thus Far](http://codepen.io/dmwellstudio/pen/VYyopo?editors=101)

```
   jQuery('#myTable').each(function () {

            jQuery('td', this).each(function () {

                if( jQuery('.demo-class').hasClass("ws_is_all_day_event") ) {
                    jQuery(".ws_is_single_day_header").addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
                }


             })

        })
```

Stupidly, what am I missing here?

Comment: This is basic jquery my advice look into selectors and maybe parent() function and try to do it yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This Code-**  You need to use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/),[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(function(){   
    $('#myTable tr td div').each(function () {      

        if($(this).hasClass("ws_is_all_day_event"))
        {
            $(this).closest('td').addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
        }

    });
});
```

**[Working Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/vdtjh7rc/)**

Answer (score 1):

You just need one liner for this:

```
jQuery('#myTable').find('.demo-class.ws_is_all_day_event')
                  .closest('.ws_is_single_day_header')
                  .addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
```

This line: `jQuery('#myTable').find('.demo-class.ws_is_all_day_event')` finds the element with the both classes applied on it. If it finds one then it traverses up the adds the class to the `.closest('.ws_is_single_day_header')` closest element with this class `.ws_is_single_day_header` and then adds  the class `ws_has_all_day_event`.

```js
jQuery('#myTable').find('.demo-class.ws_is_all_day_event').closest('.ws_is_single_day_header').addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
```

```css
.ws_has_all_day_event{font-weight:bold; color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
   <tr>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tues</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="ws_is_single_day_header">
     <div class="demo-class">Event 1</div>
     <div class="demo-class ws_is_all_day_event">Event 2</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="ws_is_single_day_header">
     <div class="demo-class">Event 1</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 2</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 3</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 1</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 2</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="ws_is_single_day_header">
     <div class="demo-class">Event 1</div>
     <div class="demo-class">Event 3</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made this waaaay overcomplicated, You don't need any loops whatsoever.

```
$('#myTable td div.demo-class.ws_is_all_day_event').parent('td')
                                                   .addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gboVBL

Answer (score 0):

Try this: iterate all `td`s to check if it has any `div` having `ws_is_all_day_event` with `class="demo-class"` then add `ws_has_all_day_event` to its parent `td`-

```
jQuery('#myTable').each(function () {
   jQuery('td', this).each(function () {
     //check if demo-class has ws_is_all_day_event
     if( jQuery('.demo-class',this).hasClass("ws_is_all_day_event") ) 
      {
          //here this refers to td
          $(this).addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following Code:

```
if( jQuery(this).find('.demo-class').hasClass("ws_is_all_day_event") ) {
     jQuery(this).addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yypmQE)

Here is Complete Jquery Code:

```
  jQuery('#myTable').each(function () {
      jQuery('td', this).each(function () {
          if (jQuery(this).find('.demo-class').hasClass("ws_is_all_day_event")) {
              jQuery(this).addClass("ws_has_all_day_event");
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could find all divs with 'ws_is_all_day_event', then find the parent and apply the class 'ws_has_all_day_event'.

```
  jQuery('#myTable').each(function () {

                jQuery('.ws_is_all_day_event').each(function () {                   
                    jquery(this).parent().addClass('ws_has_all_day_event')                  
                 })

            })
```

An example to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/a0eak3w6/. Hope it helps.